# Specific key codes for certain Android keyboard symbols?

Tags: java, android, symbols

I am trying to assign a variable to a certain keycode if a char equals something. For example, `'` would put the variable equal to `KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE`.

Right now, I am trying to find keycodes for `?` and `|`. Is there a keycode for these two symbols?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, can you please give an example....?

Comment: @Arsal lmam I want the keycodes for '?' and '|' symbols if there are any. Otherwise is there any other way to enter those into the text field? I know on a normal keyboard they are shift based keys, is there anything I have to do with that?

Comment: Just like there is a KEYCODE_A, which is used for both 'a' and 'A', the keycodes for '?' and '|' are likely the same as for '/' and '\', respectively, as they are located on the same keys on a keyboard (at least on my US keyboard).  My guess would therefore be KEYCODE_SLASH for '?', and KEYCODE_BACKSLASH for '|'.  However, you should be able to confirm this easily by logging key events and the pressing those characters.

Comment: @pathfinderelite KEYCODE_SLASH enters / and KEYCODE_BACKSLASH enters \. I need the shift versions, ? and |, to be entered.

Comment: I think your confusing *key codes* with *characters*.  They are not the same.  Like I said before, 'a' (lowercase) and 'A' (uppercase) are different characters, but can be associated with the same keycode.  Also, not all characters have an associated keycode, and likewise not all keycodes are associated with a character (e.g. KEYCODE_HOME).  Perhaps [KeyCharacterMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html) would be of interest to you.

Comment: @pathfinderelite so how would I get the shift keys with those keycodes? Right now when I send the command it does the non-shift keys.

Comment: I edited your question for readability and removed the `keycode` tag, which is for JavaScript.